# How to dynamically import a component in sitecore jss inside next js application?

Tags: jss, sitecore-api, nextjs, react

I know the conventional way of dynamically importing a component :

```
const Report = dynamic(() => import('PowerBIComponent'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

But since application uses `[...path]` to catch routes and build page I am unable to do that there.

`PowerBIComponent` is the name of component whose rendering is added on certain route from sitecore.

Can anybody help !

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/pull/727   this is link of added feature. Cannot find for next js.